# Wildcard Firebase Query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any possibility to insert wildcards in my Firebase query?

```
let query = await Firebase.db.collection('lokale').where('name', '==', name).get();
```

e.g.

```
let query = await Firebase.db.collection('lokale').where('name', '==', %name%).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't search a document which matches the substring, like in your case, but you can u integrate firebase with [Algolia](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search#solution_algolia) and search for documents which contains substring.