# Firebase get all documents with specific input string

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
let info = "every doc that starts with input preferable where i can place a limit on"
firebase.firestore().collection("usernames").doc(info);
```

I want to make a search bar where I get all users depending on the value I type in.
And I'm not sure how to do that exectly. basicaly I want to get all docs in the collection usernames that contain some input string

Comment: There is no way to get the documents where a field **contains** a specific substring. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62244283/wildcard-firebase-query/62244968#62244968 and more

Answer (score 0):

To start with, what you have done with the code above is create a document with an id of the string 'info'. Only one unique id could exist which would make querying unnecessary. In order to do a string search it would also be best to split the string into an array. II assume what you want to do is something like:

```
let info = "some string to go in document"
info = info.split(" ");

// Add a new document with a generated id.
firebase.firestore().collection("usernames").add({
    info: info
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});
```

Then you can query all documents in the collection to see if the info array contains a certain string word:

```
let check = "string"

firebase.firestore().collection("usernames").where('info', 'array-contains', check).get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
});
```

Hope this is helpful, its a difficult problem